# Android 2D game simple engine or framework

Tags: java, android, frameworks, 2d, game-engine

I would like to port my simple 2D game to Android.

So I will need some methods/a simple framework cause I am new to Android and it would be a lot of work to create my own. First I choose the Kilobolt framework (http://kilobolt.com) which is great but I would like to work with Bitmaps instead of Images. Therefore I couldn't work with Screens and the whole framework is based on Screens.

Do you know any small framework or engine that can do this job? I don't need constant FPS cause nothing changed until the user touches the Screen. So a lot of frameworks/engines are "overpowered".

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/). Along with being able to publish to Android, it has capabilities to export to HTML, Mac, Linux, Windows, and iOS.

Comment: Came here from Google, is LiGDX free when doing all those things? I'm deciding between this and AndEngine, of course if LibGDX is free and allows for exports to other platforms then it's the way to go!

Comment: @RED_: Yeah! It's completely open source under the Apache license.